# CakePHP detailed request processing

Tags: cakephp

Do you know any resource (tutorial, documentation) from which I can understand the way is proccesed an HTTP request in CakePHP?

I would like to see which classes are instanciated, what methods are called (and what order), etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xdebug's profiler to do this: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Tutorial: http://devzone.zend.com/1139/profiling-php-applications-with-xdebug/